# raw_input is not None when there's no input

Tags: python, list

Program to input default value

```
default = [1,2,3,4]  # Passing default list
L = raw_input("Enter a list  of numbers separated by comma:")
m = L.split(",")  # Spliing the list
if raw_input == None:  # If someone doesn't enter ANY INPUT
    raw_input = default
print default  # Trying to print default input
else:
    print list(m)
```

Output:

```
Enter a list  of numbers separated by comma : [PRESS ENTER]
Result:['']
```

Comment: Just what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

raw_input is an empty string if you just press return, not None. And you don't need the two stars on the default argument.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this Paul. Please help me understand this better I dint get exactly what your trying to tell.

Comment: default = [1,2,3,4]
L=raw_input("Enter a list  of numbers sepearted by comma:")
m=L.split(",")
if L == '':
 print list(default)
else:
 print list(m)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach. You have some syntax errors and logical errors. 
And i'm using python 3, so you may want to get rid of the "()" in the print statements

```
default = [1,2,3,4] 
L=raw_input("Enter a list  of numbers sepearted by comma:")
m=L.split(",") #Spliing the list
if m[0] == "": #If someone dont enter ANY INPUT
  print (default) #Trying to print default input
else:
 print m
```

hope it helps

Here is the answer to your comment

```
def just_a_function():
  default = [1,2,3,4] #Passing default list
  L=raw_input("Enter a list  of numbers sepearted by comma:")
  m=L.split(",") #Spliing the list
  if m[0] == "": #If someone dont enter ANY INPUT
    return default #Trying to print default input
  else:
    return m

x=just_a_function()
print(x)
```

Comment: From what  i know (Not a expert in python :D) you need to be inside a function to return something. To return a list:

** i edited my answer to your question**

Comment: So what you meant to say from below line is that if any functions without passing any argument like in this case def just_a_function(): is empty so your doing this .What if we have def just_a_function(x):              #x=just_a_function()
#print(x)

Comment: what does this do?

Comment: it passes a parameter into the function.. i suggest you refer this site [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm)

Answer (score 0):

```
default = [1,2,3,4] #Passing default list
L = input("Enter a list  of numbers separated by commas:")
L.split(',') if L else default
```